# Converting flv and mp4 video format to '.ogg' using FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, vps, ogg

I have HostGator VPS server with **FFmpeg** installed. It allows me to convert `.wmv` to `.flv` as well as `.mp4` files successfully using the following commands for flv and mp4:

```
ffmpeg -i WantsABath.wmv -b 600k -r 24 -ar 22050 -ab 96k WantsABath.flv 
ffmpeg -i WantsABath.wmv WantsABath.mp4
```

but it won't allow me to convert any file format to `.ogg`.

I tried using the command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -acodec libvorbis -vcodec libtheora -f ogv output.ogv
```

by mondain but no luck with it. I am doubting that my VPS doesn't have `libtheora` installed. I tried configuring it by using SSH but I don't know how to make sure if it is installed or not. I tried checking with `php_info` but can't find anything regarding `libtheora`.

Here's my FFmpeg version:

```
FFmpeg version SVN-r19795, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al. configuration: --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --disable-mmx --enable-shared --prefix=/usr/ --enable-gpl libavutil 50. 3. 0 / 50. 3. 0 libavcodec 52.35. 0 / 52.35. 0 libavformat 52.38. 0 / 52.38. 0 libavdevice 52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0 libswscale 0. 7. 1 / 0. 7. 1 This details doean't show libtheor
```

Can anyone please suggest me something?

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration string shows `--enable-libvorbis`, which would allow you to encode to Vorbis audio, however you can't create Theora video nor write to an OGG container.

Also, your version is quite outdated — it's from 2009. Three years is a long time for a tool like FFmpeg, which is constantly developed. Hundreds of bugs have been fixed since then.

You now have the following options:

1. In your package manager, try to install a newer version if available. That'd be `yum install ffmpeg` or `yum install ffmpeg-devel`.
2. On the [FFmpeg download page](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html), you will find links to static builds (like [*gusari*](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/) or [*relaxed*](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24633983/ffmpeg/index.html)), which enable both `libtheora` and `libvorbis` as well as several other important ones you are missing, like `libx264` (for high quality h.264 video) and `libvpx` (for WebM).

   Simply download the file, extract the archive, and run the `ffmpeg` binary with `./ffmpeg` instead of the system one. There is no need to `./configure` or anything.
3. Compile FFmpeg yourself, using the right configuration flags. You can find an in-depth guide for [compilation under Ubuntu](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide) or [CentOS](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/CentosCompilationGuide), both on the FFmpeg wiki.

Comment: to install the new version i have to delete the old one ?

Comment: No no, you just download it somewhere, then run the `ffmpeg` binary, e.g. `/home/username/downloads/ffmpeg`. You might have to make it executable before with `chmod +x ffmpeg`.

Comment: if i write command using my SSH
yum install ffmpeg ffmpeg-devel
will it help me installing the new verson ?

Comment: It depends on what Linux distribution you run. The packages provided by `yum` will always be outdated – how much depends on your distro and when it was released. But give it a shot and see what you get. If not, you can always use the static builds, which is what I would recommend anyway.

Comment: min is centos x86_64 should i follow the link http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/CentosCompilationGuide

Comment: You *can* compile FFmpeg yourself but you don't have to. Try the `yum install ffmpeg ffmpeg-devel` and see if it works, if not use the [static build](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/) instead and be happy with it, and if for whatever reason this doesn't work then try compiling yourself. Please *try* these options and if they don't work for you let me know.

Comment: ok i really appreciate your support ad help by heart i will try them

Comment: using the static build ffmpeg.static.64bit.2012-10-10.tar.gz i tried extracting it using SSH, it extracted one file ffmeg but not the folder ffmpeg which is not allowing me to execute ./confiure command

Comment: You don't need to configure anything. The static build is just one executable file called `ffmpeg`. Run it as `./ffmpeg` and it'll work without compiling

Comment: FATAL: kernel too old <br>
segmenation fault
this is the error it is showing ow

Comment: i mainly did is i went to my SSH
wget http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/64bit/ffmpeg.static.64bit.2012-10-10.tar.gz 
tar xzvf ffmpeg.static.64bit.2012-10-10.tar.gz and it isgiving the abve error
the above commands extracted ffmpg
i executed ./ffmpeg

Comment: Well, as the error reads, your VPS' kernel is too old. Your only option will be to install `ffmpeg-devel` via `yum` or try and compile it from source.

Comment: i did execute command 
dl.dropbox.com/u/24633983/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-linux64-20121006.tar.bz2
tar xjvf ffmpeg-linux64-20121006.tar.bz2
./configure
Error appear: no such file or directory exist 
cd ffmpeg-linux64-20121006

Comment: @user163906 You downloaded a static build. As I already said, **you don't need to `configure`** a static build. Simply run the `./ffmpeg` binary.

Comment: should i use the command yum install dl.dropbox.com/u/24633983/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-linux64-20121006.tar.bz2 or wot plz tell me

Comment: when i simply use the command ./ffmpeg it gives me the error of kernal too old

Comment: @user163906 Well, then your kernel is too old, sorry. Contact your hosting provider to supply you with a more up to date system, or alternatively try to install FFmpeg via `yum`, or compile it from source as already explained. I cannot help you any further if you don't try the alternatives I suggested multiple times now, sorry.

Comment: am sorry for being irritated but am doing this very first time thats why trying to understand your instructions and do according to them ... i really appreciate your help and support am highly gratefull for yr assistance ... and do accept my apologies for being stupid ... Thankx

Answer (score 0):

You could try my free script from here:

http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Audio%2BVideo%2BImage%2BText%2BISO+Convert?content=92533

This does many conversions:  multimedia, audio, images, text, and more.  Might do exactly what you want.  For Linux, tested on Fedora, Ubuntu, Mint, and others.